# Make PHP call an application in another server

Tags: php, nginx, digital-ocean, saas, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a webpage (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) hosted in a `Nginx & Ubuntu & Digital OCean` server. The webpage has a part where users could submit a file and call an application by PHP. I am wondering if it is possible to host this application alone in a `Windows Server 2012 R2 & Microsoft Azure`, which I have already.

Here is an example. This is [the webpage](http://www.matrixandcompany.com/) (though the real webpage has much more contents) hosted in Ubuntu Server. The `Upload the file` button is linked to `uploadFile.php`:

```
<?php
copy($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$n1 = "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
echo "Uploaded: " . $n1 . "<br>";
exec("mono c1.exe $n1");
...
?>
```

The application `c1.exe` is developed in C# under Windows. Because its new feature uses `ode32.dll`, it cannot be run with `mono` anymore. So I have to host `c1.exe` in a Windows server.

And I don't want to move the whole website to Windows server. Moreover, if possible, I want the web address in the browser address bar to be always consistent when calling php (i.e., starting with `www.matrixandcompany.com/...`).

Does anyone know if it is possible to realise this mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use curl (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). You can create a php file in the server where the c1.exe is, and call it from the old server.

Answer (score 0):

I would transport the file to the windows server. There are many different ways to do this.

Then call a script on the remote server which will execute the binary.

I cannot think of a different AND SECURE way.